# Spring ResponseEntity not returning all object attributes

Tags: java, json, spring

I am using JPA to return an object from a database using a rest controller. My problem is that when I use the `repo.findOne()` method to return a single object, and I return that single object, the JSON returned to the client is missing most of the objects attributes.
i.e. return `new ResponseEntity<>(objectA, HttpStatus.OK);`

However if I place objectA into an array, and return the array
i.e. `return new ResponseEntity<>(arrayWithObjectA, HttpStatus.OK);`
the correct JSON is returned to the client with all attributes.
Can anyone explain why this is so?

Thanks

Comment: Have you exposed all your entity's properties (getters/setters)?

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve] of your code. Otherwise, all you will get are guesses.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @Juan:Sorry for responding late, but I live in south Texas, and this has not been the nest of times! All attributes are exposed via getters and setters. It appears that it is only the nested classes that are not appearing the JSON. For example:

Answer (score 0):

Create a **ResponseHandler.java** file and write below code

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

public class ResponseHandler {

    public static ResponseEntity<Object> generateResponse(HttpStatus status, boolean error,String message, Object responseObj) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            map.put("timestamp", new Date());
            map.put("status", status.value());
            map.put("error", error);
            map.put("message", message);
            map.put("data", responseObj);

            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(map,status);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            map.clear();
            map.put("timestamp", new Date());
            map.put("status", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
            map.put("message", e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(map,status);
        }
    }
```

Now in your api use

```
return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(HttpStatus.OK,false,"Write some message", objectA);
```

Return type of your method should be `ResponseEntity<Object>`